# EF Core “InvalidOperationException: Include has been used on non entity queryable” on IQueryable

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have the following schema:

```
public class Post {
    public string Id {get;set;}
    public string Content {get;set;}
    public AppUser AppUser {get;set;}
    public List<PostTag> PostTags {get;set;}
}

public class Tag {
    public string Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public List<PostTag> PostTags {get;set;}
}

public class PostTag
{
    public string PostId { get; set; }
    public Post Post { get; set; }

    public string TagId { get; set; }
    public Tag Tag { get; set; }
}
```

With the following db relationships:

```
builder.Entity<PostTag>()
    .HasKey(x => new { x.PostId, x.TagId });

builder.Entity<PostTag>()
    .HasOne(st => st.Post)
    .WithMany(s => s.PostTags)
    .HasForeignKey(st => st.PostId);

builder.Entity<PostTag>()
    .HasOne(st => st.Tag)
    .WithMany(s => s.PostTags)
    .HasForeignKey(st => st.TagId);
```

I'm writing a query to get all the Posts that are linked to a specific Tag, based on the provided TagId.

First I get all the posts using:

```
var postsQuery = _ctx.PostTag
                    .Include(st => st.Post)
                    .Where(st => st.TagId == {provided TagId})
                    .Select(st => st.Post);
```

Since I want to include some further data to each post, I do:

```
var postsWithExtraData = postsQuery
                            .Include(s => s.AppUser)
                            .Include(s => s.PostTags)
                            .ThenInclude(st => st.Tag)
                            .OrderByDescending(s => s.TotalVoteCount)
                            .ToListAsync();
```

But the query breaks on the first `.Include` with this error:

`EF Core “InvalidOperationException: Include has been used on non entity queryable”`

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

EDIT: Potential solution that I got to work:

```
var posts = _ctx.PostTag
                    .Include(st => st.Post)
                    .ThenInclude(s => s.AppUser)
                    .Include(st => st.Post)
                    .ThenInclude(s => s.PostTags)
                    .ThenInclude(st => st.Tag)
                    .Where(st => st.TagId == request.TagId)
                    .Select(st => st.Post)
                    .ToList();
```

Would love to know if this is a good approach or not.

Comment: Where does `AppUser` come from?  It's not in any of the code you show.

Comment: Whoops, missed it. It's part of Post. I've updated my original post.

Comment: `postsQuery` is a `IEnumerable<Post>` - at that point, you're no longer in LINQ-to-Entities (you're not querying the database), so you can't call the `.Include` method.

Comment: It's being shown as `IQuerable<Post>` for me.

Comment: Correct, but the point still stands - once you've called the `.Select()` method, you can't use Include anymore - Select tells EF to translate the LINQ expression to SQL. I wish this had more details, but basically: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/client-eval

Comment: Aha that makes sense. Basically when its converted to SQL you can't `Include` anything.

Comment: @TiesonT. Please check this fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/0Lp6XD. As per `fiddle` it is working now so Microsoft might have updated its implementation for in new version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If you change the query so that it no longer returns instances of the entity type that **the query began with**, then the include operators are ignored.

So your code is giving error. You can do like below where you can use `Includes` in your first query and use `OrderByDescending` `ToListAsync` to next.

```
var postsQuery = _ctx.PostTag
                .Include(st => st.Post)
                    .ThenInclude(s => s.AppUser)
                .Include(st => st.Post)
                    .ThenInclude(s => s.PostTags)
                        .ThenInclude(st => st.Tag)
                .Where(st => st.TagId == {provided TagId})
                .Select(st => st.Post);
                
var postsWithExtraData = postsQuery                            
                        .OrderByDescending(s => s.TotalVoteCount)
                        .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: This is pretty much what I did.

Comment: `no longer returns instances of the entity type that the query began with` - so in my original example this would've been PostTag?

Comment: Please check this fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/0Lp6XD. The `statement` I've mentioned in `answer` was from [Loading Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data) but it is updated and `no longer available`. And as per `fiddle` it is working now so Microsoft might have updated its working for new newer versions.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should write `Include and ThenInclude` and then write your `Condition`

```
var postsWithExtraData = _ctx.PostTag
                            .Include(st => st.Post)
                            .Include(s => s.AppUser)
                            .Include(s => s.PostTags)
                            .ThenInclude(st => st.Tag)
                            .Where(st => st.TagId == {provided TagId})
                            .OrderByDescending(s => s.TotalVoteCount)
                            .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: What's in your postsQuery?

Comment: You can't do `.Include(s => s.AppUser)` because `s` is `StoryTag`

Comment: I've taken your query and improved it. Looks like it's working now. See the original post.

Comment: My goal was not to write  the correct query
I just wanted to explain the cause of the problem